# Biographical password calculator

Tags: software-rec, password-recovery

I am learning about computer/digital forensics and a technique that was mentioned to finding a persons password if they are not willing to give up a password is to use a bio data password calculator that will generate passwords based on the persons biographical data. The lecturer doesn't mention any software that does this; and google has returned no results. Does anyone have any idea where I can find this type of software?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your brain is the best software and hardware to use. Birthdays, pets' names, loved ones' birthdays, etc. are all common passwords. Last 4 digits of SS number and telephone numbers are common, too. In fact, your brain may be the very best tool since it can "calculate" which of those things is most important to the user based on other hints in the biography. A computer, being cold-hearted, can't do that as well as you.

You could easily write such a program, possibly in AutoIt if you don't know any programming languages.

Comment: Both "password" and "12345" are also popular choices.

Comment: Yes but I am more or less looking for a tool that will make all possible combinations of these type of passwords based on the biographical data provided.

Comment: If there isnt one you can bet I'll most likely make one ;p